# Nginx disable SSL on local network

Tags: nginx, ssl

I'm trying to serve the same site to both the external world and my local network. If accessing from my local network, I don't want SSL (to avoid adding a certificate) and accessory no user login, whereas from the external world I want both authentication and SSL. I was thinking of something like that, unfortunately accessing from my local network always redirects me to the SSL server.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name my.server.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/../fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/../privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    include snippets/ssl-settings.conf;

    auth_basic "Restricted Content";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/auth.d/auth.pwd;

    root /var/www/html;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    include /etc/nginx/locations-enabled/*.conf;
}
server {
    listen 80 http2;
    listen [::]:80 http2;
    server_name myhost.local;

    allow 10.10.1.0/24;
    deny all;
    satisfy any;

    root /var/www/html;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    include /etc/nginx/locations-enabled/*.conf;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Browsers support http2 only with TLS. And the redirect to the SSL site is probably somewhere in a config which you don't show here.

Comment: indeed, the redirect is configured in the default site:

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

Answer (score 1):

If you have SSL for your site you should leave it on SSL also for local connections.

If you are asking to trust the certificate, this means:

- it was not configured properly in the first place
- or you are using an outdated web browser
- or the time is not configured properly on your workstation
- or you have a broken network configuration (DNS, firewall, HTTP proxy...)

As for 2017 I do not see any good reason of having a site on unencrypted HTTP.

You should use SSL for both production and development sites. Using SSL allows you also to benefit from speed improvements in HTTP2. Modern browsers do not support HTTP2 on unencrypted connections.

Comment: OP appears to be running the service locally as `myhost.local`. Won't be able to get a valid SSL for that. IMO, OP should just use internal DNS to run it on `my.server.com` just like they do externally, so they can use the same cert.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was meaning. To use only the external name and SSL with certificates signed by a public CA.

Comment: I'm already using Let'sEncrypt for valid certificates to the outside world. Now I'm talking about a home installation, I don't have, and don't really want to have an internal DNS server to deal with this. My point is to bypass security when plugged in to my LAN.

Comment: and the idea is not to have a dev and pr server, but rather serve the same app with some config differences between the LAN and the WAN.

Comment: What is the real problem you are trying to solve? SSL if it is configured properly should work transparently. Nothing to configure manually on the client side.

Comment: OP would need to install a certificat that OP does not have for the internal name

Answer (score 1):

If the only reason you are trying to avoid SSL internally is to avoid a second certificate (assuming you have www.external.com and do not want www.internal.com certificate) you can manipulate your host file or internal DNS servers to change www.external.com to your server's internal ip address.

Changing the internal DNS is a much better option since it won't break assumptions that your users access it on-site only.

I have done this successfully on several machines, mostly for sharepoint.

Comment: that would be hard to achieve on IOS devices. I would like to avoid as much as possible adding a DNS server to my home network. I'll try to add "myhost.local" to the Let's Encrypt certificate as alternate hostname, that would help.

Comment: I haven't tried with Let's Encrypt, but getting a legitimate *.local certificate can't happens since it is not recognized as a TLD.  You should look into configuring your home router as your dns server, having it point to 8.8.8.8 and just add your .local records there.